# Returning criteria matching results from a row into a single column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of data I want to be able to retrieve data from and put it into a column. Screenshot does a good job explaining what this looks like. So using criteria like "year" and "week" I want to return all the cell data that is not blank from the row that matches the year and week. Importantly I want to return it in a single column. So if there are 15 matching results across that particular week's row, I want a column that would list the 15 results.

[image: example of data set]

Comment: If a pivot table would be OK, you can easily do that with Power Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Office 365 Excel use Nest two FILTER in TRANSPOSE:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(FILTER(C:G,(A:A=J2)*(B:B=J3)),FILTER(C:G,(A:A=J2)*(B:B=J3))>0))
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah I think this would work great but I don't have the FILTER function in my desktop excel despite being on 365 ProPlus. Any reason you think that might be?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FILTER`.

Something like:

```
=LET(x, FILTER($C$2:$G$7,(($A$2:$A$7=2021)*($B$2:$B$7=3)))
TRANSPOSE(FILTER(x, x<>""))
```

Comment: I'm on a version that doesn't have the FILTER function built in unfortunately.